# SlidingPanel for Xamarin.Android

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.android

[image]I'm creating a slide view with 2 tabs, but I don't know why the part of tabs are "transparent", they take the background color and not the AppBar color..anyone knows why?

MainActivity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;

namespace M_v1
{
    [Activity(Label = "M_v1", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tablayout_navigation);

            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)FindViewById(Resource.Id.pager);
            SetupviewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        private void SetupviewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;

            PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
            adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "One");
            adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment2(), "Two");

            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the theme:

```
<style  name = "AppTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name = "windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name ="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name ="colorPrimary">#2B5C56</item>
    <item name ="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name ="colorAccent">#FFEE58</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the problem that the new TabLayout uses the indicator colour from the value colorAccent, I decided to dig into the android.support.design.widget.TabLayout implementation, finding that there are no public methods to customize this. However, I found this style specification of the TabLayout:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
<item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
<item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
<item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
<item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
<item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
<item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
<item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
```

Having this style specification, now we can customize the TabLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@id/pages_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
```